# Duplicate Header row while web-parsing using python

Tags: python, parsing, header

I was watching a tutorial about web parsing. The site itself has changed since the video was created, so I had to add a couple of lines, and now the csv file that is created by the script has two header rows. Can someone please help me figure out what I need to do to correct this? Thank you! Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    return soupdata

playerdatasaved = ""
soup = make_soup("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/")

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    playerdata = ""

    for data in record.findAll('th'):                <------ Added this line
        playerdata = playerdata + "," + data.text    <------ Added this line
        for data in record.findAll('td'):
            playerdata = playerdata + "," + data.text

    if len(playerdata) != 0:
        playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]

header = "Player, From, To, Pos, Ht, Wt, Birth Date, Colleges"

file = open(os.path.expanduser("basketball.csv"),"wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii", errors='ignore'))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved,"ascii", errors='ignore'))
```

The csv file header displays the following:

Player   From    To  Pos     Ht  Wt  Birth Date  Colleges
Player  From    To  Pos Ht  Wt  Birth Date  Colleges

I have tried deleting the header variable and the header in the file command, but to no avail. Thank you!

Comment: One set of headers is from the web site, another set is from your code. Eliminate one of them.

Comment: Thank you. I guess my question is HOW to delete one of them. As I stated, I deleted the header variable in the code and from the file.write parameters. The result is that none of the data writes to the file. So, I am left wondering HOW to delete one without losing the data??

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comment, you need to eliminate one set of headers, preferably the one in your code and keep the one from the web page. Just delete the following lines:

```
header = "Player, From, To, Pos, Ht, Wt, Birth Date, Colleges"
file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii", errors='ignore'))
```